# War file created from eclipse is not getting deployed in Weblogic 8.1

Tags: java, eclipse, war, weblogic8.x

I am exporting a war file in eclipse and trying to deploy that in weblogic 8.1 but not able to do so. JDK version provided by weblogic is 1.4 but in my path variable jdk is 1.6. However I am using compiler compliance level as 1.3 but no luck. Can anyone please tell me what is the issue here. Is there any way to create war from eclipse and deploy it to weblogic 8.1???

Comment: Are you sure your build.xml is fine? Did you try to run that war inside other server container like tomcat?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @ Azmin Yes war is working fine for every other container like tomcat and even higher version of weblogic. Just not for Weblogic 8.1.

Comment: @Taylor Not getting any error. War file just getting dumped in the path after uploading it from console page of weblogic. But no folders are created for my application. And deployed file is not visible in console also. Not sure what is the problem.

Comment: I'm stumped but I'll offer advice.  Try turning up logging, to see if you can get details on why WL is doing that.  Also, does your war have a weblogic.xml file under WEB-INF?  You shouldn't need one but if you do have one, review it to make sure there's nothing wacky in there.